# Can a function instance persist in a React functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use a function wrapper for the first time in a functional React component. I need the function to persist but it seems to get reinstated every rerender. The `fetchWithAbort` just aborts any previous requests before starting another. I know `useRef` for primitives but how do I do this with functions?

#### Wrapped Function

```
const fetchWithAbort = () => {
    let currentAbort = new AbortController();

    return (...args) => {

        currentAbort.abort();
        currentAbort = new AbortController();
        let signal = currentAbort.signal;

        try {
            return fetch(args, {"signal": signal});

        } catch (err) {
            if (err.name === "AbortError") {
                return;
            } else {
                throw err;
            }
        }
    };
};
```

#### Example Component

```
const ExampleLayout = (props) => { 
    const pageFetch = fetchWithAbort();
    const handleNextPage = async (e) => {
        ...
        const resp = await pageFetch(url);
        ...
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div id="next-page" onClick={handleNextPage}>Next</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a function inside a ref, just like a primitive.  A ref is really just an object with a current field, that can point to anything.

```
const ExampleLayout = (props) => { 
    const pageFetch = useRef(fetchWithAbort());
    const handleNextPage = async (e) => {
        ...
        const resp = await pageFetch.current(url);
        ...
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div id="next-page" onClick={handleNextPage}>Next</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Love it when it's that simple. Was thinking I wouldn't be able to call `.current`. Thank you!